# Which approach is faster when when searching for an element? HashSet vs .indexOf()

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I am implementing an algorithm in Java which searches for values which are stored in a string using stringName.indexOf(string value). Would it be faster to use HashSet and searching for an element through the HashSet rather than using the string which I am currently using?

Comment: is execution time for this algorithm really a problem in your current code? For the answer, i guess it depends on your data and environment, did you do tests?

Comment: Not necessarily no, I'm just try to make the code more efficient.

Comment: The values you're seaching for are single characters or (sub)strings?

Comment: The values I'm searching for are integer numbers. They're either 1 digit integer or 2 digit integers. The string that currently has the integer values are separated by a space. 

The search is given as follows:
if (stringName.indexOf(" "+value+" ") == -1) or
if (stringName.indexOf(" "+value+" ") != -1) 
depending on the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for a substring within a String can be quite expensive.
Since the strings you're searching for are actually Integers, you could use
`TreeSet<Integer> my_set = new TreeSet<>();`

Searching for the presence or absence would become simply `my_set.contains(my_integer)`.

This of course assumes all numbers appear only once.

Comment: @IsaacZammit [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)